# I can't send request to api

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, cors, nuxt.js

I have Nuxt JS project. I can't make a request to the Node js project I run on localhost. It gives Cors error in Network section. I can send requests with Postman, but not from the project. I added the below but my problem is not solved.

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    proxyHeaders: false,
    credentials: false
  },
```

Comment: Can you show console error output ?

Comment: CORS errors are commonly solved from the backend code, not from the frontend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something missing in my Node JS project. I added the code below in the index.js file in my Node JS project and it worked.

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```